# Golang and MySQL Encrypt

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I have this query in mySQL and I want to replicate it in **GO** with **GORM**.

This is my query in mySQL

`ENCRYPT('password', CONCAT('$6$', SUBSTRING(SHA(RAND()), -16))`

and this is what I was doing in GOLANG.

`` db.Exec(INSERT INTO `user` (`user`,`password`) VALUES(?, ENCRYPT(?, CONCAT('$6$', SUBSTRING(SHA(RAND()), -16)) ), username, password) ``

It keeps returning an error saying FUNCTION user.ENCRYPT does not exist.

I am using **GO** `Go 1.15.15` and **GORM** `gorm.io/driver/mysql v1.3.2`
`gorm.io/gorm v1.23.2`

Comment: Don't use such code in the first place. Passwords should *never* be stored as cleartext or encrypted, not even for password recovery (an extremely insecure practice). The only safe way is to salt and hash the password with a strong cryptographic algorithm *multiple times*. A common number is 1000 iterations. Applications should never decrypt passwords, they should hash the user's input and compare it to the stored value.

Comment: On top of that, this code is sending the password to the server in cleartext. Googling for `Golang password storage` various results, including [this one](https://astaxie.gitbooks.io/build-web-application-with-golang/content/en/09.5.html) that shows how easy it is to use bcrypt for secure password hashing and comparison. Other results show a similar technique.